# sql insert row based on other table value

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I have 2 tables called table1 and table2. table1 has key, condition, level and conditionvalue columns and table2 has key and value columns.

**table1 rows**

```
key         condition  level     conditionVal
 1              >        error       10
 1              =        info         5    
 2              <        warning      5
 2              >        info         20
```

I will get inputs(key and value) from user or other source and that values I need to insert into table2 based on the following condition.

if key is 1 and value is > 10 or value is equal to 5 then i need to insert.
if key is 2 and value is > 20 or value is less than 5 then i need to insert.

How to acheive this using sql insert statement.

Comment: which DBMS? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL,...?

Comment: Have a search for Dynamic SQL for your prefered DBMS

Comment: CASE in sql can help you?

Comment: I am sqlite3 for my C application

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
IF EXISTS(
           SELECT 1
           WHERE (@Key=1 AND (@value>10 @value=5) ) OR (@Key=2 AND (@value>20 OR @value<5))
                                                                                            )

INSERT INTO Table2 (column1) VALUES (@values)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
INSERT INTO table2 (KEY, value)
  SELECT KEY , conditionVal 
    FROM table1 
    WHERE KEY IN
      (SELECT KEY
      FROM table1
      WHERE (KEY        =1
      AND (value        >10
      OR value          =5) )
      OR (KEY           =2
      AND (value        >20
      OR value          <5))
      AND 
    conditionVal IN
      (SELECT conditionVal
      FROM table1
      WHERE (KEY        =1
      AND (value        >10
      OR value          =5) )
      OR (KEY           =2
      AND (value        >20
      OR value          <5))
```

Comment: Table1 rows are dynamically added. So I need a dynamic solution